# MongoDB: Sort distinct keys by number of occurances

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a bunch of repository data that I've scrapped from Github. Each repository has a `language` key and with pymongo I am able to list all the languages in my database with `db.distinct('language')`. I would like to sort the list by the number of occurrences so that the first language is my list is the language associated with the most repositories. Is it possible to do this in one query instead of querying the database for the count of each language?

Comment: See http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Nicolas Rinaudo and JohnnyHK, I was able to figure out this solution. The idea is to group each repository based on language and sum the number of documents. Then the groups can be sorted by the new key.

```
db_languages = db.aggregate([
     {"$group": {
         "_id": {
             "language": "$language",
         },
         "num_repos": {
             "$sum": 1,
         }
     }},
     {"$sort": {"num_repos": -1}}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is a simple map / reduce. The advantage is that you could use it to aggregate additional information, such as the number of commits, committers, files...

It might be too heavy a solution for what you want, though. I'm not entirely familiar with the modern aggregation framework, but I believe that if there's a solution other than map / reduce, that's where you're likely to find it.